# How to intuit 'only if'?

Tags: logic, intuition

I already know, and so  ask NOT about, the proof of:   [$A$ only if $B$   =   $A \Longrightarrow  B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463407/53259).
Because I ask only for intuition, please do NOT prove this or use truth tables.

**My problem:** I try to avoid memorisation. So whenever I see this statement, I always need to pause for 5 minutes to remember my linked post above, in order to determine the meaning.
This pause reveals deficiency in my knowledge that stifles me. So please help me dig deeper. How can this statement be naturalised?

Comment: I have to pause often. I don't see it as a gap in my knowledge or my understanding. Mathematics can be complicated, and it requires precision and careful attention to details. Sometimes you just have to accept things and then get used to them.

Comment: @turkeyhundt Thanks, but how does that help? Sorry; I don't see the deeper meaning.

Comment: I would add that part of the reason this confuses you is likely that it is not how we use the word "if" in every day conversation.

Comment: This isn't really an explanation, but a mnemonic. i think of it as the opposite direct of "$A$ if $B$," which is an alternate way of saying "If $B$ then $A$." So "$A$ only if $B$" is the oppositve implication.

Comment: It might help to consider the "if" as meaning "when", such as "$A$ only when $B$", thus leading to "$A$ means that we must have $B$".

Comment: "I try to avoid memorisation.": Math is going to be hard... You had to "memorize" what the word "if" means, you will have to memorize what "only if" means too.

Comment: Here's a way of thinking about it: $A$ only if $B$ means $A$ can only happen if $B$ "happens first".  That is, if $A$ (happened), then $B$ (must have happened beforehand).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, no, no. It has nothing to do with order or time.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well, the sequence of events doesn't *change* the logic.  I'm just throwing it in here to make the language clearer.

Comment: But it obscures the meaning, and gives the wrong intuition of implication in mathematics. It is such a common error that you should avoid perpetuating it. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't see how it obscures the meaning.  Little in math has any "chronological" order, but the everyday example of physical causality is a useful mnemonic for implication.  Event $A$ causes event $B$, so if $A$ occurs, then $B$ occurs later.  I think that this is a fine mnemonic for someone who has seen implication enough to know that it isn't tied to a sequence of events.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Quite a few beginners have a hard time with the fact that implication doesn't mean what the standard "if" means. Causality is a very dangerous intuition for "if $A$ then $B$" in general.

Answer (score 5):

There have been some comments about this requiring memorization or it being different from the way the word is used in normal conversation, but this simply isn't true. It's English.

You can walk the dog only if you have a leash. Therefore, if you can walk the dog, it follows logically that you must have a leash. Can walk the dog implies have a leash.

You can legally drive a car only if you have a license. Therefore, if you can legally drive a car, it follows that you must have a license. Can legally drive a car implies have a license.

Etc.

Answer (score 3):

I understand "A only if B" as "A can be true *only* in those possible worlds where B is true also".